# returning something from a linked list

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list

Can anybody tell me why my main program is printing out 9460301 instead of 350?
I'm just trying to insert a struct as a single item into a linked list. The struct has atrributes x and y. I then wish to print out the x attribute of the struct in my linked list. I have a huge program written out, and I tried stripping it down on this post just to what's neccessary to view for this new issue that has arisen for me.

My chunk struct and Linkedlist class are as follows:

```
struct chunk{
    int x;
    int y;
};

template <class T>
class linkedList
{
public:
    class node
    {
    public:
        ///node class attributes
        T mPayload;
        node* mNext;
        ///constructor
        node(T toucan):mPayload(toucan),mNext(NULL)
        {}
        ///destructor
        ~node()
        {
            ///cascading delete
            if(mNext)
                delete mNext;
        }
        ///node class methods
    };

    ///linkedList class attributes
    node* mStart;
    ///constructor
    linkedList():mStart(NULL)
    {}
    ///destructor
    ~linkedList()
    {
        ///initializes the cascading delete.
        if(mStart)
            delete mStart;
    }
    ///linkedList class methods
    T mReturnT(int indx)
    {
        if(!mStart)
        {
            T emptyList;
            return emptyList;
        }
        else
        {
            node* cur;
            for(int i = 0; i<indx+1; i++)
            {
                if(cur->mNext == NULL)
                {
                    cout << "Indx out of range. Deleting last item." << endl;
                    break;
                }
                cur = cur->mNext;
            }
            return cur->mPayload;
        }
    }

    void mInsertHelper(node* blah, T data)
    {
        if(blah->mNext != NULL)
            mInsertHelper(blah->mNext, data);
        else
        {
            blah->mNext = new node(data);
            blah->mNext->mNext = NULL;
        }
    }

    void mInsert(T data)
    {
        if(mStart == NULL)
        {
            mStart = new node(data);
            //mStart->mPayload = data;
        }
        else
            mInsertHelper(mStart, data);
    }

    T mPop()
    {
        ///Removes the last item in the list,
        ///and returns it.
        if(!mStart)
            return NULL;
        else
        {
            node* cur = mStart;
            while(cur->mNext)
            {
                cur = cur->mNext;
            }
            T var = cur->mPayload;
            delete cur;
            return var;
        }
    }

    int mSize()
    {
        if(!mStart)
            return 0;
        else
        {
            node* cur = mStart;
            int counter = 1;
            while(cur->mNext)
            {
                cur = cur->mNext;
                counter++;
            }
            delete cur;
            return counter;
        }
    }

};
```

And my main.cpp:

```
int main()
{
    chunk head;
    head.x = 350;
    head.y = 600;
    linkedList<chunk> p1Snake;
    p1Snake.mInsert(head);

    cout<<p1Snake.mReturnT(0).x<<endl;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't follow the Rule of Three.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialise `cur` before iterating through it.

```
node* cur;                                  // <-- UNINITIALISED!
for(int i = 0; i<indx+1; i++)
{
    if(cur->mNext == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Indx out of range. Deleting last item." << endl;
        break;
    }
    cur = cur->mNext;
}
return cur->mPayload;
```

That first line should be:

```
node* cur = mStart;
```

And I think you should use `indx` instead of `indx+1` in that loop...  Unless you were using a *dummy-head* scheme, which you're not.

The logic inside the loop for detecting out-of-bounds is a bit wrong, also.  How about revamping the whole thing:

```
node* cur = mStart;
while( cur && indx > 0 ) {
    cur = cur->mNext;
    indx--;
}

if( !cur ) {
    cout << "Indx out of range." << endl;
    return T();
}

return cur->mPayload;
```

Comment: This was very helpful! :) Before, I had indx+1 because I didn't know what was wrong, and I was just experimenting.